# Zend RESTful Authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, rest

I have a website (call it siteA) I used php and Zend, I am trying to implement an api to access the restricted areas of my site(SiteA) from another(call it SiteB).

I would like to be able to authenticate user on siteB with SiteB credentials, have an html iframe to siteA where the user has been Authenticated via the API.

I am new and don't really know if I am headed in the right direction.

So far I was thinking about using a restful api, and  outside the frame the user is validated but in the frame the user is not.

Suggestions and help?
And my code is as follows:

----- SiteB user/index.php ----

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $postdata = http_build_query(
   array(            
    'userid' => 'someid',
    'key' => 'somekey',
    'public' => '1'
   )
  );

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
   )
 );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_get_contents('https://www.siteA.com/api', false, $context);
?>

<iframe src="https://www.siteA.com/" width="950" height="700"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

----- SiteA ---------

```
<?php

class ApiController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    }


    public function indexAction() {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){        
            $data = $this->_request->getPost();
            $this->_authenticateApi($data);
        }
        else{
            //error
        }

}
 public function _authenticateApi($data){
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db_local');

    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('sometable');
    $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('id');
    $authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('key');


    $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['id']);
    $authAdapter->setCredential($data['key']);

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

    if($result->isValid()){
        if($data['public'] == "1"){
            Zend_Session::rememberMe(1209600);
        }else{
            Zend_Session::forgetMe();
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem recently.  Is there a reason you must use an iframe?  It feels kind of hackish to me.

There are lots of ways to do this, but in my reading, it seems like a Best Practice is to make the API require clients to authenticate using HTTP Auth Basic, and to use HTTPS (an SSL Certificate) to encrypt the connection.  The API does not manage sessions in this case!  Every request contains the Auth Basic header, just like a regular web browser would do if you were directly browsing your API.

With your SiteB then, when the user logs in, you'd store their credentials in your `$_SESSION` or somewhere similar, and use them every time you make an API request.

[RESTful Web Services Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801688), by Subbu Allamaraju, is a great book I read recently that discusses this and other important RESTful API details.

By the way, it's not really RESTful unless your client is able to figure out the URLs all by itself just given an entry URL and knowledge of the media types the API features.  Search for HATEOAS for more.

Also, if you try to do all this in JavaScript and SiteA and SiteB do not share the same domain, you may be forced to use JsonP to handle your API requests.  While it can be done, IMHO it's undesirable.  Use `Zend_Http_Client` in your SiteB's PHP code to do all the API communication.  This way you get around the domain name issues.  This also keeps your API hidden from prying eyes (right-click, view source!) and minimizes the potential for any cross-browser compatibility issues to interfere with your site's core functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a token, do the auth with JS get a token that you store in a Javascript variable and the use that token to do the "new" connection to the site A or site B.

Read also on OAuth for getting a idea on security issues. Not sure what your final objective is so... These are my 2 cents.

Best regards,